# Azure Data Factory Derived Column RegexReplace

Tags: regex, azure, azure-data-factory

Is there any way to reference any of the other columns on a `regexReplace` using string interpolation and also Case Insensitivity?

Something like:

```
regexReplace("Hola Phillip", /${first_name}/gi,'[First Name]')
```

I would like that the column ends up with the following string: "Hola [First Name]"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter is just a string. You can formulate it using any string expression construct using other columns.